# Outlook Macro intermittent permission error

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I know nothing about VBA, I managed to put together a very simple macro that allows me to SaveAs emails via rules:

```
Sub sTXT(myMail As Outlook.MailItem)
 strname = myMail.Subject
 myMail.SaveAs "C:\Users\ss127w\Box Sync\maildump\" & strname & ".txt", OLTXT
End Sub
Sub Test()
    Call sTXT(ActiveExplorer.Selection(1))
End Sub
```

This has been working flawlessly for many many months, I've been exporting the same 2 types of emails that come in  without issue.  Well, today I tried to set up a new rule for a different email and this macro gives me a permission error:

```
Outlook cannot complete the save due to a file permission error.
```

I did not make any changes to the macro whatsoever.  I started testing the macro on random other emails and noticed that it works on some and not others.

Now if I were to manually do a SaveAs, I'm able to save any email to the folder defined in the macro.

I suspect that the special characters in the subject line is causing issues, but I haven't done enough trial and error to really be able to conclude this (the subject line has a colon (:) in it).

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that the special characters in the subject line is causing issues, but I haven't done enough trial and error to really be able to conclude this (the subject line has a colon (:) in it).

You are correct - the colon will cause issues.

If you try using Windows Explorer to edit a filename to include a colon, you will receive the message:

> A file name can't contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > |

The best thing to do is convert any such characters in your subject to some other character, e.g. instead of

```
strname = myMail.Subject
```

you might use

```
strname = Replace(myMail.Subject, ":", "_")
```

to change any colons to underscores instead.

Or you could go for the full

```
strname = Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace( _
          Replace(myMail.Subject, "\", "_"), _
                                  "/", "_"), _
                                  ":", "_"), _
                                  "*", "_"), _
                                  "?", "_"), _
                                  """", "_"), _
                                  "<", "_"), _
                                  ">", "_"), _
                                  "|", "_")
```

if you want to.  Obviously, the choice of replacement character is up to you - you could even replace them with `""` if you just want to get rid of the character.

Comment: I had a similar error even when I didn't have any special characters. Perhaps the long path name was causing problems? I completely renamed my messages to unique integers and it started working.